# Copying files (specifically photos) from a macbook to a USB

Tags: bash, shell

Copying files (specifically photos) from a macbook to a USB. Ps. i am new to bash and shell and all that, so a description on how to do it too is very much appreciated (sorry if bad english)

Comment: Do you really need to do it in command line?

Comment: yeah i did some searching on it, and i think i got the basic bash. I know how to copy files and stuff like that. But i really want a script on the usb, that when run, finds and copys all photos to the usb. If possible of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things to get you started...

You can get the mount point of an external, physical drive like this:

```
diskutil list -plist external physical | plutil -p - | awk -F\" '/"MountPoint"/{print $(NF-1)}'
```

So, if you want that in a variable do:

```
usb=$(diskutil ...)
echo $usb
```

**Sample Output**

```
/Volumes/MUSIC
```

You can get a list of `JPG`/`jpg`/`JPEG`/`jpeg`/`PNG`/`png` files in the users' HOME directories with:

```
find /Users -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg -o -iname \*.png
```

Simplistically, you *could* now exec `cp` for each file you find to copy it to your USB drive. However, there are some issues with that - what if you have a file called `a.jpg` in two different directories - only the second one to be copied will end up on your USB.

```
find /Users -iname   ...   -exec cp {} "$usb" \;
```

Comment: Thanks i will try that