# How to I scan for and return a list of external drives on Mac OSX? Equivilent code for windows included

Tags: c++, macos, usb-drive

I've made a usb backup function for my cross platform application, it works for Windows just fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to scan for the volume labels and path in Mac OSX IE "F:/USB123". **How do I best/most easily achieve the equivilent of the below code for Mac?** -- I am aware that I can't use the Win API, hence my question of what to replace it with.

I've included the struct for the below code.

The function returns the number of external usb drives found and fills two vectors with the label and the path of each usb device respectively.

```
struct ESDriveDescription
{
    std::string path;
    std::string label;

    ESDriveDescription() = default;
    ESDriveDescription(const std::string &path, const std::string &label)
        : path(path), label(label)
    {}
};



int ESFileUtils::getExternalStorageDevicePaths(vector<ESDriveDescription> &paths){
        // Letters in alphabet * 3 characters per drive path, + nul term + final nul
        // NOTE: constexpr not supported in vs2013
        static const DWORD DRIVE_BUFFER_SIZE = 26 * 4 + 1;
        static const DWORD VOLUME_LABEL_MAX = 32;

        const char* removableDriveNames[26] = { 0 };
        char allDrives[DRIVE_BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
        int numRemovableDrives = 0;

        DWORD n = GetLogicalDriveStringsA(DRIVE_BUFFER_SIZE, allDrives);
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < n; i += 4) {
            const char* driveName = &allDrives[i];

            UINT type = GetDriveTypeA(driveName);
            if (type == DRIVE_REMOVABLE)
                removableDriveNames[numRemovableDrives++] = driveName;
        }

        char label[VOLUME_LABEL_MAX] = { 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < numRemovableDrives; i++) {
            const char* driveName = removableDriveNames[i];
            GetVolumeInformationA(driveName, label, VOLUME_LABEL_MAX, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            paths.emplace_back(driveName, label);
        }

        return numRemovableDrives;
    }
```

Comment: WinAPI functions are specific to Windows OS and as such can't be used on other OS-es. You would need to consume the Mac OSX specific APIs / libraries.

Comment: That's my point, what do I use as a replacement for Mac? I haven't found anything suitable.

Comment: This should get you started... https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001264/2836621

Comment: I don't think learning how to do it in bash will help will it?